# Apache aceder de um ficheiro .html a outro .html em outro diretório

Tags: html, apache

Estou a usar o Apache para aceder remotamente a uma página html, substituí o ficheiro **index.html** que esta na pasta `/var/www/html` por um ficheiro meu que pede uma autenticação e redireciona a página para um outro ficheiro `.html.
window.location.replace('../ControlCenter/index2.html');`

O ficheiro **index2.html** esta localizado em `/var/www/ControlCenter`, estou usando o seguinte comando para retroceder um diretório e aceder ao respectivo ficheiro `(../ControlCenter/index2.html)` mas ao testar no browser não consigo aceder ao ficheiro, pois acusa o erro

> 404 not found

alguém sabe como é possível a partir do ficheiro html que acedo com o meuip:80 aceder a outros ficheiros no meu computador sem que os mesmos estejam na mesma pasta!
Se colocar os ficheiros todos na mesma pasta `(.../var/www/html)` consigo passar de uns para os outros sem problema, mas o que acontece é que em vez de aceder diretamente ao ficheiro `index.html` aparece a lista dos ficheiros existentes na pasta para selecionar qual quero correr e perde-se a parte de só aceder aos outros ficheiros depois de validar a autenticação.

edit: Consegui resolver o problema temporariamente renomeando novamente o ficheiro como **index.html**, assim tenho todos os ficheiros necessários na mesma pasta e quando acedo pelo browser passo directamente para o ficheiro de autenticação!
Surgiu um novo problema, como faço para conseguir aceder fora da minha rede, já li algures que tenho que alterar algumas permissões, mas não sei quais nem onde, alguém sabe o que alterar ou onde posso encontrar um tutorial como fazer?